# Grease pencil hold frame/extend frame

Tags: grease-pencil

I just started playing around with 2d frame by frame animation with Grease pencil. And it really has so much potential to be an amazing 2d animation software.

There is one huge thing that bothers me a lot, I have looked around for hours now trying to find an solution. But cant seem to find it. !

Basically I do my animations on 2s(a keyframe every 2 frames) So what I have done is that I have a bunch of frames for my animation. But I noticed that I didnt have enough frames. So I want to insert a frame(still on 2s) between 2 of the frames I already have. Now I can actually do this in Grease pencil, but the workflow it is so slow and tedious. First i have to insert frame inbetween, then move this frame and all frames after 1 frame forward, then I need to select all frames after the newly selected one and move them 1 frame more to get the timing right. Usually in my experience doing this kind of action should be simple one click thing, because you need to do that alot if you wanna add frammes . But in grease pencil this will take forever. Is there a way to do this smoothly?

So basically looking at the picture, I want to insert a frame where the marker is on the timeline, And it should be spaced just as the previous frames. And I want to do this preferably with a 1 or 2 click solution.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your example you can set the timeline on the 9th keyframe, then hover the mouse over the right side of the dopesheet timeline and Ctrl click (select all keyframes from here to the end), then press G 2 enter. Now you're ready to draw your Inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Actually, writing this answer made me realise how convoluted it was, so today I learnt to write add-ons and wrote one that does the same thing in just one keypress. Get it here: [Greaspencil Nudge Frames](https://github.com/bergamote/greaspencil_nudge_frames).

---

This is indeed a common option in 2D animation software that's lacking in Greasepencil, but it's still early days and I hope that <kbd>E</kbd>, for *extend*, will eventually do that (right now it just does a normal grab). Also note that Blender has always been more keyboard shortcut focused than other software, that tend to have icons for everything.
Here's a slightly faster way do this, but essentially the same as the other answer, starting exactly from your screenshot:

- Press <kbd>]</kbd> to select every keyframes after the cursor
- <kbd>G</kbd> to grab
- Move the mouse to the right by 2 frames (or press <kbd>2</kbd>)
- click to validate (or press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)